# How to create a buffer from WMS / Google Maps API?

Tags: wms, google-maps, buffer, intersection

I have a collection of points from a WMS of GeoServer I need to show a buffer.

1. Let's assume that these points are locations of commissaries and that the buffer is the 'area of responsibility' around the commissaries. The area of responsibility can be defined by col:distance or in my code.
2. If the buffer have intersection send me alert, is possible?

WMS: GeoServer

Map: googlemaps

Application: PHP and JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't have a collection of points from your [WMS](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/reference.html) you have a picture of some points. If you need the points themselves then you need to use a [WFS](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html) to fetch them.

Once you have the points in your application you can use [`turf.js`](http://turfjs.org/) to produce buffers and check for intersections.

If you prefer to handle this on the server (may be there are a lot of points) then you should look into [WPS](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wps/index.html) services to handle buffering a WFS layer and saving it as a WMS layer.

Comment: Thx Iant, i'm beginner in GIS an d use of wms, wfs,... , but i need a solution for gmap api, your solution is for mapbox :(.

Comment: it's for GeoServer actually

Comment: :( can u send an example? please.